# Using Not before and between To infinitives

Tags: grammar

1. I made excuses to not go to school.
2. I made excuses not to go to school.

Are both of them correct?

Comment: They're both correct. The first one seems more "formal" to me, the second more conversational.

Comment: See [split infinitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_infinitive).